# Find the eigenvalues of a matrix with ones in the diagonal, and all the other elements equal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

Let $A$ be a real $n\times n$ matrix, with ones in the diagonal, and all of the other elements equal to $r$ with $0<r<1$.

How can I prove that the eigenvalues of $A$ are $1+(n-1)r$ and $1-r$, 
with multiplicity $n-1$?

Comment: Any ideas of your own...?

Answer (score 13):

The matrix $A$ can be expressed as
$$
A=ruu^T+(1-r)I
$$
where $u=(1,1,\ldots,1)\in\mathbb R^{n\times 1}$, and $I$ the identity matrix in $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$.

So if $Av=\lambda v$, with $v\ne 0$, then
$$
\lambda v=Av=r\langle u,v\rangle u+(1-r)v
$$
where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the standard inner product in $\mathbb R^n$. The above implies that
$$
(\lambda-1+r)v=r\langle u,v\rangle u,
$$
which in turn implies that,

either

- $\langle u,v\rangle =0$, which happens for $n-1$ linearly independent vectors (as many the the dimension of the perpendicular hyperspace to $u$), and in this case
  $$
  \lambda=1-r,
  $$
  and hence the eigenvlaue $\lambda=1-r$ has multiplicity $n-1$,

or

- $\langle u,v\rangle \ne 0$, which means that $v$ is a multiple of $u$, and the corresponding eigenvalue is obtained for $v=u$:
  $$
  (\lambda-1+r)u=r\langle u,u\rangle u,
  $$
  i.e.,
  $$
  \lambda=r\langle u,u\rangle +1-r=r(n-1)+1.
  $$

Comment: Really great proof!

Comment: You can simplify your argument a lot if you simply write $$A=r\,uu^T+(1-r)I=nr\,\frac{uu^T}n+(1-r)\frac{uu^T}n+(1-r)(I-\frac{uu^T}n)\\ = (nr+1-r)\,\frac{uu^T}n+(1-r)\,(I-\frac{uu^T}n).$$ Then you read directly that the eigenvalues are $1-r$ with multiplicity $n-1$ and $nr+1-r=1+n(r-1)$ with multiplicity $1$.

Comment: @Yiorgos S. Smyrlis Why in the last bullet point does the inner product being nonzero imply that v is a multiple of u? This isn’t true for general vectors as far as I’m aware. Is it because v is a nonzero eigenvector?

Answer (score 9):

The determinant is invariant if you add to any row (column) a linear combination of other rows (columns). Then you can first subtract to every row the row right below it and you get
\begin{vmatrix} 
1 -\lambda& r & r & \cdots & r\\
r & 1 -\lambda & r & \cdots & r\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
r & r & r & \cdots & 1-\lambda
\end{vmatrix}
equal to 
\begin{vmatrix} 
1-r-\lambda & r-1+\lambda & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 1-r-\lambda & r-1+\lambda & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
r & r & r & \cdots & 1-\lambda
\end{vmatrix}
and now starting on the second column add to each column the one on it right like
\begin{vmatrix} 
1-r-\lambda & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 1-r-\lambda & r-1+\lambda & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
r & 2r & r & \cdots & 1-\lambda
\end{vmatrix}
and when you do it for all of them you have
\begin{vmatrix} 
1-r -\lambda& 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 1-r -\lambda& 0 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
r & 2r & 3r & \cdots & 1 + (n-1)r-\lambda
\end{vmatrix}
finally using the cofactor formula for the determinant you get the polynomial
$$
(1-r-\lambda)^{n-1}(1+(n-1)r-\lambda)=0
$$
which has the roots you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

It's clear that $1 - r $is an eigenvalue whose corresponding eigenspace is $n - 1$ dimensional (it's the null space of a matrix consisting only of $1$s).

On the other hand by inspection the column vector consisting only of 1s is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1 + (n-1) r $and the multiplicity must be $1$ since we already have $n - 1$.

Comment: Why is it clear that $1-r$ is an eigenvalue? It seems you were able to find this by inspection?

Comment: @lamanon the matrix $A - (1-r)I$ is the matrix with an $r$ in every entry. The nullspace of this matrix has size $n-1$ since the rank is just $1$.