# Eigen values of special matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ whose diagonal elements are all "$1$" and all other elements are of the form $\frac{-1}{n}$ where  $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n >1$ is the number of rows or columns of $A$. Since $A$ is symmetric and diagonally dominant with positive diagonal entries, it is positive definite.
 Can we get an expression for its eigenvalues using some kind of decomposition or by other standard approach ?

This matrix clearly has a special structure but I am unable to utilize its properties.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/904926/determinant-of-a-rank-1-update-of-a-scalar-matrix-or-characteristic-polynomia)

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/689111/find-the-eigenvalues-of-a-matrix-with-ones-in-the-diagonal-and-all-the-other-el) (which is addressed in my first link) is a little more specifically geared towards your question.

Comment: Long story short: the eigenvalues will be $1/n$ with multiplicity $1$ and $(n+1)/n$ with multiplicity $(n-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! They are always $\dfrac{n+1}{n}$ with multeplicity $(n-1)$ and the "last" is $\dfrac{1}{n}$

$$\frac{n+1}{n},\;\frac{n+1}{n},\ldots,\frac{1}{n}$$

The characteristic polynomial is
$$P(\lambda)=\frac{(-1)^n \left((\lambda  n-n-1)^{n-1} (\lambda  n-1)\right)}{n^n}$$

Determinant is $D=\dfrac{(n + 1)^{n - 1}}{n^n}$

Eigenvectors are special, too

For instance if $n=5$ they are the rows of this matrix
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

For $n=6$ the following
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

and so on

Hope it helps