# Is there a term for a matrix of 1's but with 0's along the diagonal?

Tags: matrices

Is there a term for a matrix that is like the identity matrix but with the values swapped?  That is, 1's everywhere except the diagonal which has 0's.

```
[[0, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 0]]
```

Of course, that's easily created with something like abs(numpy.eye(4) - 1).  But, does it have a name or at least a phrase that describes it?

Comment: What's special about this matrix?

Answer (score 4):

It can be well described as [a rank one update to a scalar matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/904926/determinant-of-a-rank-1-update-of-a-scalar-matrix-or-characteristic-polynomia).  These are asked about a lot; see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/689111/find-the-eigenvalues-of-a-matrix-with-ones-in-the-diagonal-and-all-the-other-el) for example.  As Exodd points out, we could also your matrix the adjacency matrix of the complete graph.

A convenient way to write this matrix is as $M = \mathbf 1 \mathbf 1^T - I$, where $\mathbf 1 = (1,1,\dots,1)^T$ and $I$ denotes the identity matrix.

Answer (score 2):

This is a special case of matrices of the form

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} a & b & \ldots & b\\ b & a & \ldots & b\\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\ b & b & \ldots & a\end{pmatrix},$$
which are [circulant matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix).

For its determinant see here: [Determinant of a specially structured matrix ($a$'s on the diagonal, all other entries equal to $b$)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86644/determinant-of-a-specially-structured-matrix-as-on-the-diagonal-all-other-e)

Answer (score 0):

Matrix associated to complete graph?